# how to change backcolor for disabled ComboBox

Tags: winforms

how to change backcolor for disabled c# ComboBox for more Readablity

Answer (score 2):

You can't, the colors used to draw disabled controls are system colors.

A disabled ComboBox is a Label.  So put a Label underneath the ComboBox and instead of disabling it, hide it.